# How do I add custom error messages in the Django Rest Framework API Key library?

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have implemented the Django Rest Framework API Key library for Authentication in my project and it is working well, however I noticed that

> "403 Forbidden"

with

> { "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided" }

is given whenever there is any issue. For example, if the key has expired then these details are given, if the key has been provided but is invalid then these details are given, and so on.

I want to be able to tell the client what exactly is wrong - because for an expired key: "credentials were not provided" is not correct - because credentials were provided, it's just that they're expired!

Is this possible - or even safe to do?

This is the library: https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom message to your error by adding a msg to your exception

example:

```
class AppUserView(GenericAPIView, CreateModelMixin):

    serializer_class = AppUserSerializer
    queryset = AppUser.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        user = request.data.get("user")
        try:
            email_address = EmailAddress.objects.get(user=user)
            if email_address.verified == True:
                return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                msg = gettext_lazy("email address is not verified")
                raise exceptions.NotAuthenticated(msg=msg) 
        except BaseException as e:
            print(f"Unexpected {e=}, {type(e)=}")
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, data=e.args[0])
```

I don't know if that would work with your library, but it might give you an insight

Comment: Authorization happens before the view is accessed so I don't think this would work :(